# C# List of List initialization, { new List<int>() {1,2,3} } not working?

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to create a List of List of Integers, and I wanted to do it "inline" without using .Add, but it doesnt work, why?

```
// This is working
List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>();
lists.Add(new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 });
lists.Add(new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 });
lists.Add(new List<int>() { 7, 8, 9 });

// This compiles, no red, but is not working, the list stays empty
List<List<int>> secondList = new List<List<int>>();
{
    new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 };
    new List<int>() { 7, 8, 9 };
};
```

Also, why the second example needs ; between the lists and not just "," like with a list of some type?

**P.S. Solved** I just realized that I had another issue, I wrote it as `List<List<int>> list = new List<List<int>>(); { ... };` in my code and that first semicolon shouldnt be there, a simple typo :D and it was asking for ; on the lines and was giving me errors when I was using ,

Solution:

```
List<List<int>> secondList = new List<List<int>>
{
    new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 },
    new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 },
    new List<int>() { 7, 8, 9 }
};
```

Comment: Second list should be:`List<List<int>> lists1 = new List<List<int>>()
            {
                new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 },
                new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 },
                new List<int>() { 7, 8, 9 },
            };`

Comment: I just realized that I had another issue, I wrote it as List<List<int>> list = new List<List<int>>(); { ... }; in my code and that first semicolon shouldnt be there, a simple typo:D and it was asking for ; on the lines and was giving me errors when I was using ,

Comment: But the code you have mentioned in question can't even compile. Yet you say it does?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani I just wrote the two different examples, I was not trying to initialize "list" variable twice, I left a free row between the two examples, dunno why stackoverflow wrote it in the same body. Anyway I changed the name of the second list to avoid this confusion.

Comment: @Darkbound Then answer your own question and accept it please in order to get this question out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second example has incorrect syntax. You should use comma as separator, not ;.

```
var lists = new List<List<int>>
{
    new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 },
    new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 },
    new List<int> { 7, 8, 9 }
};
```

This works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that my actual problem was elsewhere, I tried to do it with "," initially but it was not building, see my first comment for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The second example does not compile, and should instead look like this:

```
List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>()
{
    new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 },
    new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 },
    new List<int>() { 7, 8, 9 }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized that my actual problem was elsewhere, I tried to do it with "," initially but it was not building, see my first comment for explanation.

Comment: No problem. In my opinion, object initialization (like you do in your second example), is cleaner code, than the first example, so it's good you got this cleared up!

Comment: Yea, I just wanted to practice LINQ and wanted to see if Ill manage to get all of these numbers extracted into a single collection, now it works:)